# PHP - Trazer o resultado de uma tabela de acordo com a mensagem mais recente de outra tabela?

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Então.. Tenho 3 tabela:

```
user:
    | ID | NOME | SOBRENOME |
    | 01 | Igor | Ferreira  |
    | 02 | João | Henrique  |
    | 03 | Rose | Beltão    |

following:
    | ID | user1_id | user2_id |
    | 01 |    01    |    02    |  User 1 > Segue User 2
    | 02 |    02    |    01    |     -- User 2 > Segue User 1
    | 03 |    01    |    03    |  User 1 > Segue User 3
    | 04 |    03    |    01    |     -- User 3 > Segue User 1
    | 05 |    03    |    02    |  User 3 > Segue User 2
    | 06 |    02    |    03    |     -- User 2 > Segue User 3

chat:
    | ID | user1 | user2 |      mensagem      |       data       |
    | 01 |   02  |   03  | ola Rose.          | 30/07/2015 08:25 |  De João > Para Rose
    | 02 |   03  |   02  | Oi João, como tas? | 30/07/2015 08:28 |  De Rose > Para João
    | 03 |   02  |   03  | Estou bem, e você? | 30/07/2015 08:29 |  De João > Para Rose
    | 04 |   01  |   02  | Rose você esta ai? | 30/07/2015 09:11 |  De Igor > Para Rose
```

Em uma `div` estou listando os **Amigos** que o usuário segue:

```
$sqln = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM users 
                            WHERE (id = '$id') 
                            OR (id IN (SELECT user2_id FROM following WHERE user1_id='$id'))
                            ORDER BY id ASC");
```

[image: Div de amigos!]

Porem o único defeito é que ela somente lista os usuários que a seguem, e oque eu realmente preciso é que ela (`div`), **SIM**, liste os usuários que a seguem, mas de forma mais dinâmica trazendo os usuários que ela segue, mas os únicos que conversaram com ela e que do **TOPO** para o **ULTIMO** de acordo com as mensagens mais recentes**..

[image: Listar como WhatsApp]

É basicamente fazer com que a pesquisa na `query` que lista as tabela interligadas (**User** e **Following**) também entre em contato com a tabela **Chat** como se trouxesse uma `ORDER` de acordo com as mensagem recentes entre os usuários que o user vai seguir.

Vi exemplos assim mas não deu certo:

```
SELECT u.id, u.nome, MAX(c.data_hora) AS last_msg FROM chat c 
INNER JOIN users u ON c.id_para = u.id
WHERE c.id_de = 1
GROUP BY c.id_para ORDER BY last_msg DESC;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
    u.id,
    u.foto,
    u.username,
    u.nome_us,
    u.sobrenome_us,
    u.tell
FROM users u
   RIGHT JOIN following f
      ON f.user1_id = '$id'
   INNER JOIN chat c
      ON ((c.user1 = '$id' and c.user2 = f.user2_id) or (c.user1 = f.user2_id and c.user2 = '$id'))
WHERE
   u.ID = f.user2_id
GROUP BY
   f.user2_id
ORDER BY
   c.data DESC, c.hora DESC
```

Ao executar o select acima você estará trazendo as colunas "id", "foto", "username", etc. Esses nomes de coluna que devem ser usados para ler os dados obtidos:

```
$id_q = $num_q['id'];
$foto = $num_q['foto'];
$username = $num_q['username'];
```

Comment: Pergunda: Como trazer os dados de cada tabela em um while? Fiquei bastante confuso

Comment: Sou muito ruim com INNER JOIN... ;(
http://i.imgur.com/JPeVPbm.png @rocmartins

Comment: Eu acho que eu só não sei como pegar o nome, foto, id do usuário dessa forma kkk, pq mandei uma outra mensagem de outro usuário e apareceu mais um http://i.imgur.com/dZUCyZ8.png.. so não estou conseguindo retornar os dados de quem mando.. dentro da tabela user preciso pegar, ID, FOTO, USERNAME, NOME, SOBRENOME, TELEFONE

Comment: @PedroQuezado Em que tabela está foto, username e telefone?

Comment: TABELA user >> id, username, nome, sobrenome, foto, telefone @rocmartins

Comment: Resposta editada @PedroQuezado

Comment: Dessa vez não troce resultado http://i.imgur.com/viMKq2R.png @rocmartins

Comment: Provavelmente isso acontece devido aquele if com os IDs. É meio no escuro, mas tenta agora com o right join no começo.

Comment: testei com `WHERE u.id = f.user2_id GROUP BY  c.id_de` e pegou... >>
http://i.imgur.com/QwPCQ0o.png

Comment: Beleza. Resposta editada com as suas correções.

Comment: NOVAMENTE PROBLEMA @rocmartins.. Se eu por a `GROUP BY u.id`, onde ele pega todas as mensagens de um usuário e joga numa unica caixa, porem ele não ordena de acordo com as menagens mais recentes na tabela **chat** >> http://i.imgur.com/DH4yvUi.png  --- Agora se eu tirar a `GROUP BY u.id` ele lista realmente de acordo com as mais recentes, porem ele joga todas as mensagens sem querer saber de repetições: http://i.imgur.com/GlhXPEL.png. 
Como posso resolver??

Comment: @PedroQuezado, alterei o group by para o id do usuário 2, dá uma olhada.

Answer (score 1):

Pedro, tenta essa query abaixo. Porém, não sei é o que você precisa.
Precisava criar um banco temporário para testarmos melhor.

Se você quiser use o [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) para criar um banco temporário e passe-nos o LINK para te ajudar melhor.

```
SELECT
    NOME, SOBRENOME
FROM
    USER
INNER JOIN
    FOLLOWING ON FOLLOWING.USER1_ID = USER.ID
INNER JOIN
    CHAT ON CHAT.USER2 = FOLLOWING.USER2_ID
ORDER BY 
    DATA 
DESC
```